# Can I configure SMTP in IIS, so it relays to a remote SMTP server?

Tags: security, iis, email, smtp

I want to configure SMTP on my web server, so that any email sent through the SMTP server is relayed to a remote SMTP Server. The IIS SMTP server would have to use SMTP authentication, and use the host name, username and password (as if configuring a normal email client).

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it' completely possible, and relatively easy to configure.

I've got a couple of articles about SmartHosting on my web site that will probably help:

http://www.christopherlewis.com/SmartHosting/SMTPSmartHosting.htm 

and
http://www.christopherlewis.com/SmartHosting/SMTPSmartHostingPt2.htm

They're written towards Exchange 2003, but Exchange 2003 used IIS's SMTP engine, so the settings are the same.

Bascially, you right click the SMTP site, select properties, Delivery tab, Outbound security, and enter your credientials in the Basic Authentication fields.  Back on the Delivery tab, you then click Advanced and enter the remote SMTP server name in the SmartHost field.

### **Editing**

The links above are no longer available.

Try http://intellitect.com/configuring-windows-smtp-server-on-windows-2008-for-relay/.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to add anything to the Domains section? Or should this be enough? Is there an easy way to test, as I have configured as above, but cannot seem to get it working.

Comment: You shouldn't have to set anything in the domains section - as for testing, I'd run WireShark, and filter on SMTP traffic.  You can check the SMTP logs, which should show the connection process.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the first hyperlink was very useful and did the trick.

Comment: I've downvoted this because the linked articles don't exist anymore.

Comment: Upvoting back - the new link is really useful!

Comment: I've down-voted because even though the new link works you should have added the content to the answer so we don't just get the same issue again with this new link

Answer (score -1):

HTH and answers your needs

http://www.cmsconnect.com/praetor/webhelpg2/Chapter_2_-_Pre-installation_considerations/Configuring_the_SMTP_Server.htm

Comment: The links is a 404

Answer (score -1):

I think you can only set outbound relays for specific domains, not blanket coverage.

http://www.isaserver.org/articles/smtprelayinboundoutbound.html

EDIT:
I've not done this before, buy maybe worth a try:

From the Server properties, you could try selelcting the 'Delivery' Tab, then advanced. In the Smart Host, type the outgoing SMTP relay IP / domain. Select OK, and then select 'Outboud Security' and enter your username / password in the basic authentication box.