# Mail Error:The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am using following code to send email. The Code does not working it getting the error message

```
try
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(mFrom, "xyz@gmail.com",mSubject,mMsg);
    SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
    mySmtpClient.Credentials = ICredentialsByHost)CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    mySmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    mySmtpClient.Send(message);
}
catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (SmtpException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

The following SmtpException exception is been catched

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503333/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Please configure the required mail settings in the web.config based on the delivery method or host that you use.

Have look at the following URL
[how to configure smtp settings in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233108/how-to-configure-smtp-settings-in-web-config)