# Umbraco 7.5 form submission Issue

Tags: email, form-submit, umbraco7, receiver

I use UmbracoForms for uploading video by user . a very simple form which needs some approvals , so my question is :

as the following attachment, I have a workflow called "**sending email to admin**" . 
[image]

In this picture , I set the sender and receiver email statically.

[image]

but I cant receive any submission email in admin inbox.

whats the problem with my settings

Comment: Are you sure a smtp server is configured in your web.config?

Comment: @Mark no , actually I didnt know I should set anything on web.config. do u have any sample page url?

Comment: Check out the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233108/how-to-configure-smtp-settings-in-web-config